# Where to put the direct object

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, direct-objects

Is it grammatically acceptable to use the words in the order they are put in the sentence:

> People shouldn’t take at face value every bit of information they might find in blogs.

Answer (score 3):

> People shouldn’t take [at face value]<sub>*(adjunct of manner)*</sub> [every bit of information they might find in blogs] <sub>*(direct object)*</sub>.

When the direct object is that long, it is better to specify the manner in which the action is performed before it. When the object is shorter, the verb is not normally separated from its direct object. Consider:

> People shouldn’t take [this information] [at face value].